# getServerSideProps API fetch takes way too long and makes website look unresponsive -- Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am fetching data via an API on pageload. The API is pretty slow and I get that getServerSideProps can't do anything about that. My issue is that it doesn't start the navigation untill the data has been fetched... which takes about 6-8 seconds. This makes it seem like the website is unresponsive.

I want to have a skeleton of my page load while I am waiting for the data to be fetched.

Is this possible?

Here is what my code looks like (simplified - I'm making two api calls in gSSP which is part of the reason it takes so long)

```
`export async function getServerSideProps () {
  const [data1Res, data2Res] = await Promise.all ([

    fetch ('url1'),
    fetch ('url2')

  ]);

  const [data1, data2] = await Promise.all([
    data1Res.json(), 
    data2Res.json()
  ]);
  
  return {
    props: { data1, data2 }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}`
```

I have tried using getInitialProps or getStaticProps and that doesn't help. I've also tried adding page loading to the _app.jsx which doesn't do anything.

I'm thinking about just putting my fetch inside an API route and then calling that API route on the client side... only problem is that will probably make the API load even slower bc then there is two API calls. However then there will at least be instant navigation and a skeleton so that the user knows that the site isn't responsive.

Is this an issue unique to Next.js? It seems like this would be a pretty common problem. Hopefully I'm missing something basic here.

Basically I don't care that my API call takes so long, but I just need it to not feel so egregiously unresponsive.

Comment: _"I want to have a skeleton of my page load while I am waiting for the data to be fetched."_ - You can, by fetching the data on the client-side instead. There's no way around waiting for the data to be fetched when using `getServerSideProps`. If you want to provide feedback while the API call is made, use client-side data fetching. Alternatively, with Next.js 13 you can use [server components with Suspense](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching#parallel-data-fetching) which could be used for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to modify links for fetching data? If so, perhaps only fixing API could help. Else you can just fetch it on initialization and then filter by search query